# Notification not have icon when defining as `setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)` for ForegroundService

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, foreground-service

I am building Notification for my ForegroundService on Android, but my icon is not showing:

```
return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentText("Sdílení polohy je aktivní")
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .build();
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an icon set that only uses white color and put the mipmap folders, on a transparent background.You do not use any color other than white. [Icon generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification#source.type=clipart&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_outline_call_white_36pt_3x)

And use this code for icon tint:

```
 .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.notification_icon)
 .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor))
```

Comment: It needs to be white even for notification alone? Because some apps have colored icon

Comment: You can look material design [page](https://material.io/design/platform-guidance/android-notifications.html#behavior). Only one color set.